# How to add a default filter to the Custom Table Datagrid web part

Tags: kentico

Using Kentico 10 - I have a custom table datagrid component that displays data. I have created an alternative form for this custom table with a code name of "filter". How do I get this alternative form filter to display above my datagrid? I am not using the default admin tools for editing my custom table data - the filter works there - but I want to embed it in a templated page and can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom table datagrid has Filter Name property, which means this web part could be used with filter, so you need to [add filter](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/filtering-and-paging-data) to your page template.

Filter transformation you've created does not change the appearance of the custom table datagrid web part on the live page, it just allows you to create custom filter for that particular custom table in Kentico admin.

Answer (score 2):

By default, if you are using the OOTB listing viewers, the filter will only show if there are more than 25 records.  If you want you can change this by adding a web.config key.  But keep in mind this will change the default number of records displayed before paging for all Kentico listing pages not just the custom table grid.  I should mention this is ONLY for listing viewers int he Kentico UI, not on your public pages.

```
<add key="CMSDefaultListingFilterLimit" value="10" />
```

Comment: Thanks Brenden. I'm displaying 50 records by default. I think I am running up against what you said - "this is only for listing vieweres in the Kentico UI, not on public pages" - I am trying to do this for a public page. Any workaround, or any other thoughts?